# grant all privileges on db.* to user?

Tags: postgresql, privileges, sql-grant

(select version() PostgreSQL 11.6, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit)

I created a new user:

```
create user bob with password 'some_password_string';
```

I am in a db called 'GoogleData':

```
grant all privileges on GoogleData to bob;

SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: relation "googledata" does not exist
```

I am able to add bob to specific tables in GoogleData by specifying schema.table e.g.

```
grant all privileges on reporting.ecom_dashboard to bob;
```

That works, except there are too many tables to grant access to one by one. I am also unable to grant access to public.

Tried:

```
grant all privileges on public to bob;
SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: relation "public" does not exist
```

Tried iterating over specific schemas like so:

```
grant all privileges on reporting.* to bob;
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "to"
  Position: 46
```

1. How can I grant all privileges to Bob at the database level? When I tried I got error 'ERROR: relation "googledata" does not exist' (Where googledata is the db in question)
2. GIven I cannot seem to grant access at the db level, how can I grant bob privileges at the schema level `grant all privileges on schema_name.* to bob;`?

Comment: [Database-level grants need to explicitly use the `DATABASE` keyword](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-grant.html): `grant all privileges on database GoogleData to bob;`. If you don't specify the kind of object, it falls back to `TABLE` (that keyword is optional) and causes the error you got.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the suggestion. I did try that: `select current_database(); returns GoogleData`. Then `grant all privileges on database GoogleData to bob;` results in error `SQL Error [3D000]: ERROR: database "googledata" does not exist`

Comment: If you really have uppercase letters in your database name, you'll need to use `database "GoogleData"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I grant bob privileges at the schema level

You your looking for the option [`on all tables in schema`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html)

```
grant all privileges on all tables in schema public to bob;
grant all privileges on all tables in schema reporting to bob;
```

You probably also want to [change the default privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) so that this is also applied for tables created in the future.